# Orfeo toolbox and MacOs, installation fails

Tags: orfeo-toolbox

I am trying to install orfeo toolbox in my MacAir with Maverics. I am using homebrew but the installation fails with the following error log:

==> Downloading //downloads.sourceforge.net/project/orfeo-toolbox/OTB/OTB-3.20/OTB-3.20
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/orfeo-3.20.0.tgz
==> cmake .. -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE= -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE= -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/tmp/orfeo20150720-4244-1cjwrtd/OTB-3.20.0/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/tmp/orfeo20150720-4244-1cjwrtd/OTB-3.20.0/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".

READ THIS: //git.io/brew-troubleshooting

These open issues may also help:
orfeo 5.0.0 (https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/pull/41363)
orfeo fails to build on 10.10.3 (https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/41275)

I went to the github forum and the issue has been opened, but it was not 100%clear which is the solution

Answer (score 1):

I've commented on the issue tracker on github. I don't get why the formula is trying to install version 3.20 which is pretty old. I was thinking that there is formula for OTB 4.X